# Extremely slow JDBC query

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

## Problem

I have a JDBC query that runs 8-20x slower than the same query in Python (using cx_Oracle).  I would expect some normal % variance between languages but 8 or more times slower seems like I'm doing something wrong.

I'm not including the actual query since it shows some business logic (table structure, naming, etc.) but I don't think it should be very relevant since I'm comparing Python vs Java execution times, and not trying to profile the query itself.  However it is a left join across 7 tables and pulling values from 25 columns across those tables.

The query runs against tables that have millions of rows and ultimately returns 28,705 rows as expected.

The Python code is actually doing more than the Java code because in Python I loop over the results and extract the values into objects.  For the Java code I simply loop over the ResultSet to fetch the data but I don't process the data/rows in any way beyond that.

I'm hoping there's some obvious/non-obvious setting(s) I'm missing in the Java code that brings it more inline with the Python execution times.

## What I've Tried

I've tried what I consider the obvious solutions which were also the main items to address in other SO posts.  These include:

- Updating the Oracle JDBC drivers
- Trying different values for the fetch size
- Running a more current version of Java (12 vs 8)

## Code and Timings

I have timings from the various configurations and they all run many times slower than the Python code.

**Note** The output is slightly cleaned up to remove the driver version from each line for brevity.

Java Code:

```
    public void runJdbc() throws Exception {
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);

        // Pull driver version info
        OracleDatabaseMetaData meta = (OracleDatabaseMetaData)(conn.getMetaData());
        String name = meta.getDriverName();
        String version = meta.getDriverVersion();
        String driverInfo = name + '.' + version;

        // Run the query for each fetch size and time operations
        int sizing[] = {100, 1000, 5000, 10000, 25000};
        for(int s : sizing) {
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            stmt.setFetchSize(s);

            // query
            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
            long querySeconds = (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) / 1000;

            // iterate over results just to fetch them, no additional processing for now
            int count = 0;
            long start2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            while ( rs.next() ) {
                count++;
            }
            long rsSeconds = (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) / 1000;

            System.out.println("Execution completed: driver=" + driverInfo + ", fetchSize=" + s + ", rows=" + count + ", query.seconds=" + querySeconds + ", resultSet.seconds=" + rsSeconds );
        }

        conn.close();
    }
```

Execution Times:

```
Python:

    Completed query. rows=28705, queryTime=11.48
    --- 13.22 seconds ---
```

```
Java 8:

    java version "1.8.0_72"
    Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_72-b15)
    Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.72-b15, mixed mode)

    Driver 11.2.0.1.0
        Execution completed: fetchSize=100, rows=28705, query.seconds=1, resultSet.seconds=107
        Execution completed: fetchSize=1000, rows=28705, query.seconds=4, resultSet.seconds=98
        Execution completed: fetchSize=5000, rows=28705, query.seconds=18, resultSet.seconds=100
        Execution completed: fetchSize=10000, rows=28705, query.seconds=34, resultSet.seconds=108
        Execution completed: fetchSize=25000, rows=28705, query.seconds=100, resultSet.seconds=117


    Driver 9.3.0.0.0
        Execution completed: fetchSize=100, rows=28705, query.seconds=1, resultSet.seconds=121
        Execution completed: fetchSize=1000, rows=28705, query.seconds=5, resultSet.seconds=109
        Execution completed: fetchSize=5000, rows=28705, query.seconds=19, resultSet.seconds=111
        Execution completed: fetchSize=10000, rows=28705, query.seconds=37, resultSet.seconds=109
        Execution completed: fetchSize=25000, rows=28705, query.seconds=95, resultSet.seconds=108
```

```
Java 12:

    java version "12.0.2" 2019-07-16
    Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 12.0.2+10)
    Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 12.0.2+10, mixed mode, sharing)

    Driver 11.2.0.1.0
        Execution completed: fetchSize=100, rows=28705, query.seconds=1, resultSet.seconds=115
        Execution completed: fetchSize=1000, rows=28705, query.seconds=5, resultSet.seconds=105
        Execution completed: fetchSize=5000, rows=28705, query.seconds=18, resultSet.seconds=101
        Execution completed: fetchSize=10000, rows=28705, query.seconds=36, resultSet.seconds=100
        Execution completed: fetchSize=25000, rows=28705, query.seconds=85, resultSet.seconds=98

    Driver 9.3.0.0.0
        Execution completed: fetchSize=100, rows=28705, query.seconds=1, resultSet.seconds=118
        Execution completed: fetchSize=1000, rows=28705, query.seconds=4, resultSet.seconds=107
        Execution completed: fetchSize=5000, rows=28705, query.seconds=21, resultSet.seconds=109
        Execution completed: fetchSize=10000, rows=28705, query.seconds=37, resultSet.seconds=109
        Execution completed: fetchSize=25000, rows=28705, query.seconds=94, resultSet.seconds=109
```

## Expectations

I would expect the JDBC execution to be closer in time to the Python execution, maybe +/- 25%.  What I actually see is the JDBC query is 8-20x slower than the python query.

The worst case scenario, where I extract the data from the ResultSet in the Java code, runs 20x slower than the Python code.  If I simply loop over the ResultSet in Java then it can get as low as 8x slower.

## Update

Based on the comments I altered the code and command to fix the timing and increase the Heap, and the overall runtime is still very poor vs Python.

Code change:

```
    long rsSeconds = (System.currentTimeMillis() - start2) / 1000;
    long overall = (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) / 1000;
    stmt.close();

    System.out.println("Execution completed: driver=" + driverInfo + ", fetchSize=" + s + ", rows=" + count + ", query.seconds=" + querySeconds + ", resultSet.seconds=" + rsSeconds + ", overall.seconds=" + overall );
```

Timing:

```
java -Xms2g -Xmx32g -jar target/JdbcTest-1.0-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar 

Execution completed: driver=Oracle JDBC driver.19.3.0.0.0, fetchSize=100, rows=28705, query.seconds=1, resultSet.seconds=128, overall.seconds=129
Execution completed: driver=Oracle JDBC driver.19.3.0.0.0, fetchSize=1000, rows=28705, query.seconds=5, resultSet.seconds=120, overall.seconds=126
Execution completed: driver=Oracle JDBC driver.19.3.0.0.0, fetchSize=5000, rows=28705, query.seconds=19, resultSet.seconds=89, overall.seconds=108
Execution completed: driver=Oracle JDBC driver.19.3.0.0.0, fetchSize=10000, rows=28705, query.seconds=36, resultSet.seconds=69, overall.seconds=105
Execution completed: driver=Oracle JDBC driver.19.3.0.0.0, fetchSize=25000, rows=28705, query.seconds=92, resultSet.seconds=13, overall.seconds=105
```

## Update - Python Code

The Python code is:

```
import cx_Oracle
import time

class DataObject:
    def __init__(self, columns, row):
        index = 0

        for key in columns:
            value = row[index]
            index += 1

            setattr(self, key, value)

    def __str__(self):
        s = ''
        for k, v in self.__dict__.items():
            s += f'{k}={v}, '
        return s

class Oracle:
    def __init__(self, args):
        self.args = args

    def run(self):
        start = time.time()

        # connect
        conn = cx_Oracle.connect(self.args.ora_uid, self.args.ora_pwd, self.args.ora_dsn)
        cursor = conn.cursor()

        # run the query
        cursor.execute(self.args.query)
        columns = [column[0] for column in cursor.description]

        # fetch results
        results = cursor.fetchall()
        count = cursor.rowcount
        print(f'Query returned {count} rows')

        # create objects from the data
        dao = []
        for r in results:
            dao.append(DataObject(columns, r))

        # cleanup
        cursor.close()
        elapsed = time.time() - start
        print(f'Query completed. rows={len(dao)}, seconds={elapsed:.2f}')

        # output to validate
        for d in dao:
            print(d)

        return(columns, dao)
```

The output is:
`Query returned 28705 rows
Query completed. rows=28705, seconds=11.34`

## Driver Connection String

```
private static final String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(LOAD_BALANCE=on)(FAILOVER=ON)(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=***)(PORT=***))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=***)(SERVER=DEDICATED)))";
```

Comment: increase your heap size.

Comment: Remember to close your Statements (which also will automatically close their respective ResultSets).  Also, your second timing calculation should be using `start2`, not `start`.

Comment: Sorry about that timing mishap, I was trying to setup a simple test repro case and missed that.  It definitely explains the increase in query vs resultSet timings, but the overall run time vs Python is still an issue.

I'll fix that, close the statement, and increase the heap and try again.  Thanks.

Comment: Based on the comments I altered the code and command to fix the timing and increase the Heap, and the overall runtime is still very poor vs Python.

Posting a top level comment due to size restrictions.

Comment: can you add the python code, since that's the benchmark you are comparing to?

Comment: Well if you look a bit more your result, you should notice that the execution time depends on the number of row you fetch in the resultset. The `ResultSet` is creating during the execution so if you ask the 20k row directly, it take more time to read and create the instances. So this is not the query that takes time (**with 100row fetch, it took 1sec)**. Now, for 28k rows, this is a poor performance so I would guess you either have 1000 columns, or a lot of BLOB type column or you have a sizing problem in the JVM. You should monitor the JVM to see if you are running low on some memory.

Comment: Did you use **oci** or **thin** connection with Jdbc driver ?

Comment: What kind of table structure did you use for tests ? (field dataTypes and etc)

Comment: For the driver I'm using the thin connection:

    private static final String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(LOAD_BALANCE=on)(FAILOVER=ON)(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=***)(PORT=***))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=***)(SERVER=DEDICATED)))";

The table structure is a mirror of our live data, a join across 7 tables, pulling 25 columns from that join.  

The data is primarily Strings, longs, and a couple of timestamps.  All strings are < 100 characters except for 1 that can be up to 4k.

These are the same tables/data I queried via the Python code as well.

Comment: @scott - Can you use a network analysis tool like Wireshark to see if the Java and Python apps generate roughly the same volume of traffic when retrieving the results?

Comment: Good idea @GordThompson, I'll give that a try when I can get some time to profile this a bit more.  Thanks.

Comment: You could tune the Python code with [`arraysize`](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cursor.html#Cursor.arraysize).  Check LOB usage as already mentioned: make sure you are comparing apples with apples and not comparing one driver fetching LOB data and the other not.  If you fetching LOBs, review [ReturnLobsAsStrings.py](https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/blob/master/samples/ReturnLobsAsStrings.py).  Overall the solution to your problem seems obvious: just use Python ;-)

Comment: lol - I really wish I could use Python for this scenario but the business demands and requirements to fit into the existing infrastructure, typical story. :( . I did play around with the arraysize and the overall difference in runs wasn't large enough bother with. I'll definitely have to go back and check how the LOB data is being fetched in both scenarios to make sure it's the same, thanks!

Comment: maybe using the OCI (native) driver could help or even an older jdbc driver.